# Globally add an order_by on sqlalchemy entities?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We are migrating from MySQL to Postgresql and one of the major features of MySQL that we relied on was the fact that objects came back in the order they were inserted.  In Postgresql sort order is not guaranteed so we would like to just globally tell our SQLAlchemy entities to order by ID.

We want to avoid updating every single query we have. If we can create a subclass of Entity or hook into it somewhere globally that would be best.

Comment: There is no guarantee in MySQL either, that was pure luck and it depends on the queries and engine as well. Try some DELETE's and than some INSERT's, no more sorted output.

Comment: Well, it has worked for us for the most part, so globally sorting ID will get us closer to the expected behavior.

Comment: What did you rely on this behavior *for*?  Maybe somebody can suggest an easy substitute.

Answer (score 1):

By default it already should be returning results 'in order' unless you overrode/modified the automatic 'id' column, if it's not you may need to fiddle with your mapper.

Check out the [orm.mapper](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=order#class-mapping-api) API, specifically the order_by setting. This is done on a somewhat meta-level to the schema.